# From/at - with regard to time

Tags: prepositions

The meeting starts **at** 2 in the afternoon.

The meeting starts **from** 2 in the afternoon.

I know the first sentence isn't grammatically incorrect, I have a feeling the second one isn't either. Is the second sentence grammatically correct? Is there a difference in the meaning of these senteneces?

Comment: The second sentence is not idiomatic. An event starts **at** a certain time - it  lasts **from** a certain time **to** or **until** a later time.

Comment: "I know the first sentence isn't grammatically incorrect,"  Why?  It looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

> The meeting starts at 2 in the afternoon.

is correct and would be used in the context Although it is more usual to say 2 pm or 2 o'clock

---

> The meeting starts from 2 in the afternoon.

Although it is technically correct its use is not correct in this context. It is used where the arrival time is not binding. It is considered incorrect form, to arrive after the appointed starting time of a meeting.

> The party starts from 2 in the afternoon.

You are not obliged to arrive at 2 you could arrive later.